# pyvisa unable to connect to GPIB instrument using GPIB-USB-HS interface

Tags: python, usb, visa, gpib, pyvisa

I'm trying to communicate with an instrument (Agilent 33220A arbitrary waveform generator) using GPIB and I use the GPIB-USB-HS interface plugged into a USB port on my computer.

The instrument is correctly listed when I use NIMAX explorer (there is also a Thorlabs PM100D connected by USB):

[image: NIMAX explorer instrument listing]

However, I cannot connect to it using PyVISA.
Here is the code:

```
import visa
rm=visa.ResourceManager()
rm.list_resources()
```

The output is:

```
('USB0::0x1313::0x8078::P0003982::INSTR', 'ASRL1::INSTR', 'ASRL3::INSTR', 'ASRL6::INSTR')
```

As you can see, the PM100D connected by USB is correctly listed, but not the Agilent connected on GPIB 10.

I tried to connect directly:

```
rm.open_resource('GPIB0::10::INSTR')
```

But I got an IO error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\nanotube\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 1623, in open_resource
info = self.resource_info(resource_name, extended=True)
  File "c:\users\nanotube\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 1583, in resource_info
ret, err = self.visalib.parse_resource_extended(self.session, resource_name)
  File "c:\users\nanotube\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py", line 1381, in parse_resource_extended
alias_if_exists)
  File "c:\users\nanotube\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\highlevel.py", line 188, in _return_handler
raise errors.VisaIOError(ret_value)
pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_RSRC_NFOUND (-1073807343): Insufficient location information or the requested device or resource is not present in the system.
```

I use Python 3.6.0 on Windows 7 Pro 64 bits OS. PyVisa version is 1.8.

I don't understand what I'm missing here. Does anyone have an idea ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Is the device in use by another program?

Comment: Sorry for the long response time, I'be just seen your answer. :-) And, no, the device is not in use by another program. Really, I don't know how to make it works

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you

`rm.open_resource('USB0::0x1313::0x8078::P0003982::INSTR')`

Comment: Not really, this will connect to the Thorlabs PM100D detector (and works perfectly) but not to the Agilent 33220A through the GPIB-USB adaptor

Comment: There are few things we can try
1. Remove all devices and only connect Agilent 33220A with usb and then run rm.open_resource
2. Some devices have two USB and Visa modes try to identify, may be visa mode restricted
3. Try installing the Agilent 33220A Driver from other sources like NI